# How to save data for ACF files in custom attribute?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have added the custom image field using ACF in the product attribute. Now I am trying to save field values using custom code but it's not working. Please help me with this.

```
$attribute_options_term_id = 111;
$attachementId = 1512;
update_field( 'field_61e90325b0717', $attachementId, 'pa_manufacturer_'.$attribute_options_term_id );   `
```

But this not working.

Comment: Where are you applying this code?  Is this in a function or a page template?  To understand what isn't working, this question needs more context.

Answer (score 0):

Technically your code should work, however is...

1. your registered taxonomy 100% registered as `pa_manufacturer` ?
2. the return/saved settings of ACF tax field `field_61e90325b0717` is set to return `id`?
3. the term field key 100% `field_61e90325b0717`?

If all the above is `true` I cant see why this acf `update_field` function should not work :-/

Can you provide any more code and screenshots of `field_61e90325b0717` return settings?